# How can I efficiently perform serialization on arbitrary integral types for transmission and archival purposes

Tags: c++, c++11, serialization

I have a lot of different types of data I want to serialize to a BYTE array in a custom format.  (I plan to convert everything into a some int based representation and then use this technique)  I then want to send this data over a network to other machines and I also intend to use it to store data to files which may also travel to other machines.  I have figured out how to do most of this for integral types... however I am still struggling to write a byte swapping algorithm that avoids undefined behavior.  A lot of the implementations I've seen are either needlessly slow, or they rely on tricks that invoke UB.  What is the correct, general way to write a fast byte swap algorithm in c++?  I'd prefer c++11.  Also, can I detect one's comp/sign-mag on older systems and handle that too?  I want a wide variety of machines to be able to run this code as I plan to use it for pretty much all my binary serialization from embedded systems to web socket data until I can come up with something better.

I've looked into a few existing library implementations for serialization like protobuf, but they seem bloated and slow or they seems to use casting tricks to function which may invoke UB.  So I am looking to handle this in a custom way as well... This is a rough idea of the interface I am thinking of implementing so far, but maybe there is a better way for this too.  Regardless, here's what I've got atm:

```cpp
template<typename T>
T nativeToTwosCompLittleEndien(const T& input)
{
static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "T must be an integral type");
// ...
}

template<typename T>
T nativeToTwosCompBigEndien(const T& input)
{
static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "T must be an integral type");
// ...
}

template<typename T>
T twosCompLittleEndienToNative(const T& input)
{
static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "T must be an integral type");
// ...
}

template<typename T>
T twosCompBigEndienToNative(const T& input)
{
static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "T must be an integral type");
// ...
}
```

Comment: I used to have some really neat, really complicated template functions that handles all of the endian conversions complete with Duff's Device and other groovy <expletive deleted>. But one day, more or less on a whim, I timed them against simple loops optimized by the compiler. End result was lot of complication for no value. I also fond that working out of and into the byte buffer was faster than having an intermediary integer value.  Wound up with dumb-stupid loops around stuff like `val <<= 8; val |= bufp[index - 1];`

Comment: Basically, write simple, easily recognizable stuff and trust the compiler. Your co-workers will thank you and since humans wrote the compiler, the compiler will recognize simple patterns just like your co-workers will and optimize the living <expletive deleted> out of them. Of course this assumes you work with humans.